# Redirecionamento para outro sub-domínio com adição de atributos flash (RedirectAttributes) não funcionam

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirecionamento

Minha dúvida é relacionada a adição de atributos na interface `RedirectAttributes`. Estou adicionando dois atributos *flash* no redirecionamento, mas o redirecionamento não muda apenas a URI e sim o sub-domínio como pode ser visto no método abaixo:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/access-agency", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String acessLoginPage(@RequestParam(required = true) String email, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request){
    Login login = loginFacade.findByEmail(email);
    Agency agency = agencyFacade.findAgencyByTenantId(login.getTenantId());

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("inputFieldReadOnly", Boolean.TRUE);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("employeeEmail", email);
    return "redirect:http://" + agency.getSubdomain() + "."+ request.getServerName().replaceAll(".*\\.(?=.*\\.)", "") + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath()+"/login";  
}
```

Infelizmente não funciona! Alguém sabe me dizer se é pelo motivo de eu estar realizando o redirecionamento para outro sub-domínio e o

> RedirectAttributes

só funciona com a mudança de URI?